# Looping through object without iterator in Groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I try to iterate over an object without using `next()` iterator to get specific values.

`Recordset recordset=connection.executeQuery(strQuery);`

I use `recordset.getField("Col1");` `recordset.getField("Col2");` at this time to access variables. I try to use up content line-by-line in `JMeter` inside a `Loop Controller`,

Comment: and what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `inRowNum` property of the Recordset which can be used to "tell" the recordset which row to jump in.

Given you have the following Excel file:

[image]

- If you invoke `recordSet.inRowNum=0` - it will read `A2` and `B2`
- If you invoke `recordSet.inRowNum=1` - it will read `A3` and `B3`
- Current [Loop Controller's](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) iteration can be obtained like `vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller__idx')`

Demo:

[image]

References:

- [Fillo documentation](https://codoid.com/fillo/)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)